# Nashorn and 'with' context passed from Java

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn, javascript-engine

I am struggling with `nashorn` and `with` block. I would like to pass 'context' from java with `HashMap` and use it in my code. However, I am not able to get this working.

JS to be evaluated

```
with(ctx) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Java map to be "passed"

```
Map<Object, Object> ctx = new HashMap<>();
ctx.put("a", 5)
ctx.put("b", 5)
```

Below I prepared short class to demonstrate errors I am facing to.

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        Map<Object, Object> ctx = new HashMap<>();
        ctx.put("foo", 5);
        eval("print('1st - :)'); ctx = {'foo':'bar'}; with(ctx) {print(foo);}", new HashMap<>());
        // No exception with 'with', o seems to be properly 'in context'..
        eval("print('2nd - :)'); var o = {}; print(o); with(Object.bindProperties(o, ctx)) { print(o); } print(o)", ctx);
        try {
            // ..But it is not
            eval("print('3rd - :('); var o = {}; with(Object.bindProperties(o, ctx)) {print(foo);}", ctx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            // 'with' failure - context was not event bound
            eval("print('4th - :('); with(ctx) {print(foo);}", ctx);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void eval(String code, Map<Object, Object> ctx) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.getContext().setAttribute("ctx", ctx, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        engine.eval(code);
    }
}
```

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `print(ctx.foo);` it works because `ctx` is a special Java object implementing `Map` and it seems Nashorn handles this special case. But it doesn’t consider `foo` to be an actual property of the object. So when you use `Object.bindProperties`, it doesn’t transfer `foo` as a property. But the reason, your second example seems to work, is that it actually transferred the `toString()` method of the map as a function. So when printing the object `o`, you see the output of the `Map`’s `toString()` method as if all mappings were copied.

When you run the following program

```
Map<Object, Object> ctx = new HashMap<>();
ctx.put("foo", 5);
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.getContext().setAttribute("ctx", ctx, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
engine.eval("print(ctx.foo);"
   + "with(Object.bindProperties({}, ctx)) {"
   + " print(toString());"
   + " print(get('foo'));"
   + " print(foo); }");
```

you get

```
5
{foo=5}
5
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "foo" …
```

indicating that the methods have been transferred, but not the pseudo property `foo`. But the presence of the methods in the object opens a possibility for a work-around:

```
Map<Object, Object> ctx = new HashMap<>();
ctx.put("foo", 3);
ctx.put("bar", 7);
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.getContext().setAttribute("ctx", ctx, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
engine.eval(
     "var o={ __noSuchProperty__: function(n) { return this.get(n); }  };"
   + "with(Object.bindProperties(o, ctx)) { print( foo + bar ); }");
```

This creates an object having the special Nashorn function `__noSuchProperty__` which will be invoked for handling absent properties and calls the `get(…)` method we got from the `Map` in our case. Hence, `print( foo + bar );` will print `10` in the above example.